# JPA Foreign key in database, return object in project

Tags: java, sql-server, jpa, netbeans

I'm trying to connect my Java application to an existing database.
The database contains Personen, who have 1 Graad and Locatie. The Graad.graadNumeriek is the primary key for Graad and Locatie has an autogenerated primary key.

My goal is to return all Personen, including their Graad and Locatie.

However, when I run my error, I get the following error:

```
Internal Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name 'GRAAD_GraadNummeriek'.
Error Code: 207
Call: SELECT PersoonId, Achternaam, BackupTelefoon, Email, GeboorteDatum, Geslacht, RijksregisterNummer, Score, TelefoonNr, VerwachteDagen, Voornaam, GRAAD_GraadNummeriek, LOCATIE_LocatieId FROM Persoon
Query: ReadAllQuery(name="Persoon.getAllePersonen" referenceClass=Persoon sql="SELECT PersoonId, Achternaam, BackupTelefoon, Email, GeboorteDatum, Geslacht, RijksregisterNummer, Score, TelefoonNr, VerwachteDagen, Voornaam, GRAAD_GraadNummeriek, LOCATIE_LocatieId FROM Persoon")
```

My guess is this has something to do with SQL looking for Graad_graadNumeriek in Persoon, instead of using keys.

**Persoon**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Persoon")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Persoon.getAllePersonen",
            query = "SELECT p FROM Persoon p"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Persoon.findByName",
            query = "SELECT p FROM Persoon p WHERE p.achternaam = :persoonNaam OR p.voornaam = :persoonNaam")
})

public class Persoon implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "PersoonId")
    int id;
    @Column(name = "Voornaam")
    private String voornaam;
    @Column(name = "Achternaam")
    private String achternaam;
    @Transient
    private SimpleStringProperty voornaamProperty = new SimpleStringProperty();
    @Transient
    private SimpleStringProperty achternaamProperty = new SimpleStringProperty();
    @Column(name = "GeboorteDatum")
    private String geboorteDatum;
    @Column(name = "Geslacht")
    private char geslacht;
    @Column(name = "Email")
    private String email;
    @Transient
    private String emailOuders;
    @Column(name = "RijksregisterNummer")
    private String rijksregisternummer;
    @OneToOne
    private Locatie locatie;
    @Column(name = "TelefoonNr")
    private String telefoonNummer;
    @Column(name = "BackupTelefoon")
    private String backupTelefoon;
    @ManyToOne
    private Graad graad;
    @Transient
    private SimpleStringProperty graadString = new SimpleStringProperty();
    @Column(name = "VerwachteDagen")
    private Integer verwachteDagen;
    @Transient
    private SimpleStringProperty rol = new SimpleStringProperty();
    @Column(name = "Score")
    private int score;

    public Persoon() {
    }
```

**Graad**

```
@Entity
public class Graad implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "GraadNummeriek")
    protected String graadNumeriek;
    @Column(name = "Niveau")
    protected String niveau;
    @Column(name = "FotoURL")
    protected String fotoUrl;

    public Graad() {
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `@JoinColumn(name="joinedColumnName")` to `Graad` attribute in `Persoon class` 
And also add :
`@OneToMany(mappedBy = "graad")
 private List<Persoon> persoons=new ArrayList<>();`
 to the `Graad` file

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the column that points to Graad with @JoinColumn, JPA cannot guess the column that you are trying to join